# Get Parent Page Position on screen in an iframe

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I tried this to get the Parent screen position but its giving me 0.

```
window.parent.$(document).scrollTop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must try like this

```
$(window.parent.document).scrollTop();
```

or

```
window.parent.$(window.parent.document).scrollTop(); // if jQuery not included in child frame
```

Comment: This does not work on all iFrames only the ones that are on the same domain.